# Changing variable values in a for loop in R

Tags: r

I have written a loop for illustration purposes that loops through all the data frame values and should change the value of 'NA' cells to 0. I know this is not the best way to do it and could use mutate or some other function, but this is to illustrate the right and the wrong method.                                            The code loops through the data but does not change the value of the cells. Any suggestions will be helpful.

```
xy <- sample_data
i <- 0
j <- 0
    
for (i in 1:(ncol(sample_data1))) {
  for (j in 1:(nrow(sample_data1))) {
    if (is.null(sample_data1[i,j])) {sample_data1[i,j]=0}
    {xy[i,j] <-  sample_data1[i,j]}
    
  }                                                                                 COMPANY_NUMBER  YEAR_END_DATE   TURNOVER    NATIONAL_TURNOVER   OVERSEAS_TURNOVER
    22705            30/09/2010      793000         793000                  NA
    22705             30/09/2009    1153000         1153000                 NA
    22705            30/09/2008      609000         NA                      NA
    31700            30/09/2007      500000         500000                  NA
    44705            30/09/2006     2442000         2442000                 NA
    44705            30/09/2005     1672000           NA                    NA
    25600            30/09/2004      731000         731000                 NA
    25600            30/09/2002      990000         990000                  NA
    67700            30/09/2001     5002000         5002000                 NA
    67700            30/09/2000     7227000         NA                      NA
```

Comment: `is.null` looks for NULL value, you are interested in look for NA, then need to use `is.na` instead.

Comment: If you'd like to do it all at once `sample_data[is.na(sample_data)] <- 0`

Answer (score 0):

You have at least 3 errors:

1. Use `is.null` instead of `is.na` to look for `NA`
2. Your indices inside for loops are wrong. You used `i` defined as column index and finally use it in `[i,j]` as row index, same happens with j
3. Introduce an `xy` object for assignment, but you have to use `sample_data1`

Here is a sample code for you to run and get desired output:

```
for (i in 1:(nrow(sample_data1))) {
  for (j in 1:(ncol(sample_data1))) {
    if (is.na(sample_data1[i,j])) {
      sample_data1[i,j] <- 0
    } else {
        sample_data1[i,j] <-  sample_data1[i,j]
    }
  }
}
```

This yields as output:

```
     V1         V2      V3      V4 V5
1  22705 30/09/2010  793000  793000  0
2  22705 30/09/2009 1153000 1153000  0
3  22705 30/09/2008  609000       0  0
4  31700 30/09/2007  500000  500000  0
5  44705 30/09/2006 2442000 2442000  0
6  44705 30/09/2005 1672000       0  0
7  25600 30/09/2004  731000  731000  0
8  25600 30/09/2002  990000  990000  0
9  67700 30/09/2001 5002000 5002000  0
10 67700 30/09/2000 7227000       0  0
```

Note the better way to get this result is as @Gregor Thomas mentioned in his comment

Comment: Thanks so much-it works as I want it to!

Comment: @Ahson I`m happy this answer solved your problem, you can now accept it by clicking on the tick mark and upvote it. It´s the Stackoverflow way to say thanks.